# "Pin" link to commit reference from generic tree reference on GitHub

Tags: github

Let's say I'm on a GitHub page for a file in a repository, like so:

```
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SwiftShims/HeapObject.h#L33
```

Note that this links to line `33` and branch `master`. If I want to reference this is in an issue or pull request, I'd want a link to the current commit, so that updates to the file don't invalidate my link.

Is there a one-click way to do this?

Obviously, I can click on the commit at the top, copy the SHA, and paste it over `master`, but that's inconvenient.

Comment: Hopefully you've figured out a way to do it by now, but if not a simple bookmarklet would allow you to get the correct link to the commit and copy it to the clipboard with just one click and a **CTRL** + **C**.  You just want to copy the URL to that commit?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bookmarklet that can grab the commit URL for you.  Just copy the code below into a bookmark in your browser, then when you're viewing a page like the one you linked to above, click the bookmark.  A box will appear at the bottom of the screen like this one, containing the URL for the commit page:

[image: URL copy box]

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy the link (which will already be highlighted) and from there you can paste it wherever you need it.

Make sure that when you copy the code into a bookmark that `javascript:` appears at the beginning.  (In some browsers, it doesn't always copy over.)

```
javascript:
(function() {
  var commitLink = document.getElementsByClassName("message")[0].href;
  var linkModal = document.createElement('input');
  linkModal.type = "text";
  linkModal.innerText = commitLink;
  linkModal.contentEditable = false;
  linkModal.size = commitLink.length * 1.1;
  linkModal.style.zIndex = 10000;
  linkModal.style.border = "2px solid red";
  linkModal.style.borderRadius = "4px";
  linkModal.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
  linkModal.style.fontSize = "1em";
  linkModal.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  linkModal.style.color = "black";
  linkModal.style.padding = "3px 7px 4px 7px";
  linkModal.style.position = "fixed";
  linkModal.style.left = "37%";
  linkModal.style.bottom = "0%";
  document.body.appendChild(linkModal);
  linkModal.focus();
  linkModal.select();
})();
```